# Adding chai-as-promised to an Ember app

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm finding myself in an Ember-based app and are having a little trouble understanding how I should add the [chai-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-as-promised) helper library to it. I'm running this version:

```
$ ember --version
version: 2.4.2
node: 5.8.0
os: darwin x64
```

I started by installing via `npm i chai-as-promised --save-dev`. The library was then importable via Node. Then I have tried adding it to the `ember-cli-build.js` file using two different approaches:

As a file via `.import()`, after creating the `EmberApp`:

```
  module.exports = function(defaults) {
    var app = new EmberApp([...]);
    app.import('./node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js');
```

Via `EmberApp.toTree()` to `chai-as-promised`'s top directory:

```
return app.toTree('./node_modules/ember-cli-blueprint-test-helpers/');
```

And descending into the `lib/` subdirectory of `chai-as-promised`:

```
return app.toTree('./node_modules/chai-as-promised/lib');
```

I also tried installing via Bower and changing the above `node_modules/` based paths to `bower_components` ones, but still with the same result.

Am I importing it wrong? Or is there somewhere else I should import?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell ember-cli to add it to the test tree like this:

```
app.import("bower_components/chai-as-promised/lib/chai-as-promised.js",
           { type: 'test' });
```

otherwise it isn't available in the test suite but in the app. I got this to work in combination with `ember-cli-mocha`.

You can see how it works here: https://github.com/albertjan/ember-cli-chai-as-promised

Comment: Nice! Can't check it now beacuse Saturday but will soon

Comment: Enjoy your weekend :)

Comment: I have now tried this method, but unfortunately can't get it to place `chai-as-promised.js` in my `dist/assets/` directory. Noting that cloning your repo and doing a fresh install does however, so I'll investigate further.